# Android Studio: Getting a TextView to Wrap Around Checkbox

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, textview

I am trying to put `CheckBoxes` in the middle of a `TextView` in Android Studio that can be clicked on. I want the text to be able to change length depending on the screen size and orientation as well. Here's an image of what I'm trying to get it to look like:

[image]

I've searched pretty much all over the internet and all I've found was wrapping `TextViews` around images.

Can TextViews be wrapped around CheckBoxes and how?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put multiple CheckBoxes next to each other? Each checkbox can have a text assigned.

Comment: They need to be inside the text. This is for a card game tracker and I'm trying to get it to look just like it does on the card.